# Why does the result variable update itself?

Tags: python, datetime

I have the following code:

`result = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(seconds=60)`

```
>>> result.utcnow().isoformat()
'2016-09-23T18:39:34.174406'
>>> result.utcnow().isoformat()
'2016-09-23T18:40:18.240571'
```

Somehow the variable is being updated... and I have no clue as to how or how to stop it. What is this called? How do I prevent it?

Thank you!

Comment: Just use `result.isoformat()` to see the value of `result`. `utcnow()` returns the current time, not the time in `result`, so why are you calling that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`result` is a `datetime` object

`datetime.utcnow()` is a class method of all `datetime` objects.

`result` is not changing at all. `utcnow()` is

Comment: If you want to store the ISO time set a variable equal to result.utcnow().isoformat(). Then you can recall that value whenever you need it.